# Printing weirdness - German language, Xerox 7125

Tags: drivers, language, printing

Please read carefully to see the problem details and steps that I have taken to troubleshoot.

We have an executive at my organization who has a German language machine, Windows 7.

I have installed the German Language drivers, and have set the printer to use 'Letter' size paper rather than A4.

- I am able to print a test page just fine.
- I am able to create a word or excel document and print it just fine.

When another user emails a document to this fellow and he tries to print it, it seems to try to print in size A4.  (through with the PCL6 driver it gives error code 016-749)   This despite the printer settings still being on Letter (including the Printing Defaults).  Here are some observations:

- I have quadruple checked the printer settings.  It is on Letter.
- The document is not formatted strangely, or selected on an
  alternative paper type that I can tell - its generated by an english
  user, for christ sake!
- I have tested with PS driver, PCL6 driver, and Xerox's 'Global'
  driver.  None work.
- I can print the document just fine to a Xerox 7556 down the hall.
- I am connected to the printer by IP, but have also tried to print to
  it via a share from a print server.  No difference in results.
- If I copy the contents of the document and paste it into a brand new
  document, it prints just fine.

I'm really scratching my head here. Printer driver bug?

Can anyone suggest something else to try in order to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it is the local settings that you have to look into.  though the printer itself is set to letter size.  But due to the Version of Windows for the region that it is from, they sometime default print jobs to A4 paper format.

Try looking at printer setting on the client outlook for printer size setting.  Good luck with reading the menu in German :D

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party, but could you please clarify:

1. If you're able to print to the affected device from another computer normally, presumably with no language installed packs since this is a special user.
2. What type of documents have you tested this on? Is it ***any*** attachment? or just documents; what applications have you tested it from? I'm going to make the assumption that you've tried Word and Adobe/Alt PDF Reader to troubleshoot this

If you haven't tried this out please give it a shot, if you're able to print normally from a different device ***and*** you're able to replicate the problem on the same machine across ***several*** applications or document types then the problem may still be based on corrupt drivers, if not we may need to dig deeper.